# Accessing a specific certificate from the windows store with python

Tags: python, windows, ssl, python-pika

I am trying to connect to RabbitMQ using Pika.  We are using certificates (ssl) to do this.  Here is their (Pika's) example:

```
context = ssl.create_default_context(
    cafile="PIKA_DIR/testdata/certs/ca_certificate.pem")
context.load_cert_chain("PIKA_DIR/testdata/certs/client_certificate.pem",
                        "PIKA_DIR/testdata/certs/client_key.pem")
ssl_options = pika.SSLOptions(context, "localhost")
conn_params = pika.ConnectionParameters(port=5671, ssl_options=ssl_options)
```

This is great, if our cert files had a file path, but we are on Windows and they are stored in the windows store.  So I don't believe load_cert_chain() as provided above will work.

I am able to access (or see) the specific cert like this:

```
context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
context.load_default_certs()
certs = context.get_ca_certs()
```

But this gets a list of certs.  I don't see any obvious way to search through and grab the cert I need.  And even if I could, I am not sure how to make the code connection to "pika.SSLOptions(context,...)"

So there are two questions here, but the more important one is this:

1. How can I pull out a specific certificate from the windows store (since I don't have a file path)?

(the other question is how to connect this to Pika but I may be able to figure that out if the above question is answered)

*Note:  Pika is just a third party library that interfaces with RabbitMQ.*
*Note2:  Using Python3.5*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like, after reading some hits from [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+windows+certificate+store) that most Python libraries that deal with the Windows cert store do so to fetch [CA certs and CRL lists](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2510) and not individual certs so much.

The [`wincertstore`](https://bitbucket.org/tiran/wincertstore) library *might* be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks I did look at that, but looking at it again, it may be worth a shot.  Taking a step back, I am wondering if what I am being tasked to do is even possible.  I am being told we can NOT keep the .pem files in a windows folder, but must retrieve them from the CA/ROOT certs store.  Looking at the actual RabbitMQ documentation, I only see it saying the cacertfile, keyfile and cafile are actual paths, e.g., "/path/to/*.pem" . So either Pika is able to convert these certs file from store to an actual path, or am I am being tasked with an impossible mission.

Comment: Quick update:  Playing around with wincertstore, it has a method to get_pem() which is the actual certificate file contents.  Passing this to pika, may ultimately be what I need. Once I figure out how to get pass in the keyfile cafile and certfile all this way, I think this will work!